# Getting a PaLM API key access denied

Tags: google-api, key, google-ai-platform

I am a student and want to experiment with the [PaLM API](https://developers.generativeai.google/guide/palm_api_overview). For this, the first step is to get an API key, as stated [here](https://developers.generativeai.google/tutorials/setup). However, when I click on <kbd>Get an API key</kbd> I get an error

[image]

How can I get one?

Answer (score 4):

If anyone else ends up here, in my case it seems to be a location issue. My country is not listed in [the list of available regions](https://developers.generativeai.google/available_regions). After enabling a VPN to the US, I was able to generate a key.

Answer (score 1):

If you live in an unsupported country (e.g. the UK or Canada), you will need to use a VPN to both get yourself a key and to use it.

If you forget to enable the VPN when using it, you'll get:

```
{
  "error": {
    "code": 400,
    "message": "User location is not supported for the API use.",
    "status": "FAILED_PRECONDITION"
  }
}
```

Anywhere in the US works so if you can VPN to, say, California then you're good.